# Failed to load API definition Flask Swagger UI

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I'm working on an API using flask. I had the code for running the app so:

```
def create_app():
    """Create Flask app."""
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # accepts both /endpoint and /endpoint/ as valid URLs
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

    # register each active blueprint
    for url, blueprint in ACTIVE_ENDPOINTS:
        app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix=url)


    return app
```

So, I started to do a documentation using Flask Swagger UI, I created a static directory and into create a swagger.json file with the template. For the implementation I added this:

```
def create_app():
    """Create Flask app."""
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # accepts both /endpoint and /endpoint/ as valid URLs
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

    # register each active blueprint
    for url, blueprint in ACTIVE_ENDPOINTS:
        app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix=url)

    # swagger configs
    SWAGGER_URL = "/swagger"
    API_URL = "/static/swagger.json"
    SWAGGER_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
        SWAGGER_URL,
        API_URL,
        config={
            "app_name": "iam-challenge-juanda"
        }
    )
    app.register_blueprint(SWAGGER_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)

    @app.route("/static/swagger.json")
    def specs():
        return send_from_directory(os.getcwd(), "swagger.json")

    return app
```

When I run de app in localhost just received: **Failed to load API definition - Fetch error
NOT FOUND /static/swagger.json**

Any idea why? I think so using a correct url for swagger.json file

Comment: What's the error message in the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: can use flask automated swagger https://pypi.org/project/flask-toolkits/